# WebStorm inspect for JSDoc?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm doing maintenance in a legacy project and there's many functions lacking JSDoc comments.

I'm wondering if is it possible to make the inspector of WebStorm show me an error if some JSDoc is missing for some function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such inspections in WebStorm; but you can use [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) - it has rules for JSDoc checking - see http://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-jsdoc

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/javascript-code-quality-tools.html#ESLint for details on using ESLint with WebStorm

Comment: Just a note that JSDoc rules support has been dropped from ESLint. [https://eslint.org/blog/2018/11/jsdoc-end-of-life](https://eslint.org/blog/2018/11/jsdoc-end-of-life) They suggest using an external plugin available at [https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc)